# Android app hangs if click outside Email address matcher window in Xamarin android app

Tags: android, xamarin

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wGUXC.png)

For some days now I am stuck in a tricky situation.
**I am using email address matcher in my Xamarin android app. All is well, when I click on email , email address matcher is opening up the window that can open the email address,till now its ok. Now if instead selecting any one option from the window, if I click outside, the app hangs.**
Below is my code,

```
             if (Patterns.EmailAddress.Matcher(fieldValue).Matches())
                {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ActionSend);
                    intent.PutExtra(Intent.ExtraEmail, new string[] { fieldValue });
                    intent.SetFlags(ActivityFlags.NewTask);

                    intent.SetType("message/rfc822");

                   
                    activity.StartActivity(intent);                       
                   
                }
```

**Logically if the user wants to open close this Email Address Matcher window, is there anyway to do?
I am badly stuck here. In older version (android 6) this problem is not happening. But from android 7 onwards, the issue is there**. Need help.

Comment: have you checked logs?

Comment: I test the code you provided on Android 8.0. I could close this Email Address Matcher windows through clicking on the blank of the screen. Could you provide more details about how to reproduce?

Comment: In device log,I got a warning with Tag "MTK_FG" with message  fd< 0, init first ! Then an error with same tag and message "init failed, return!"

Comment: Hello Wendy, please check attached image, if you click on the hovered background portion outside 'share with' popup, my app crashes..

Comment: sorry it hangs no crashing

Comment: Do you have any other device or emulator to test? Does it still hangs?